# Bind user entered value to input

Tags: javascript

I think this is a simple solution for some

I have a

```
<input id="bet" type="text" value="">
<img id="calculate" src="btn-submit.png" />
```

I need to read what users entered, now only null is returned. From what I am reading online, the DOM is only reading the initial value of my empty input, so how can I bind the user entered value and submit that with my onclick?

```
const myBet = document.getElementById("bet").value;
const btnCalculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

btnCalculate.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(myBet);
}
```

Comment: access value inside of click function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Just access value inside of `click` function.
- The reason you are getting it empty because, you are accessing value only once when program runs first time, when user enter value it won't update to update it's value you can use `onchage` or other events.
- For here you have used `onclick` so we should access it's value inside of `onclick` function.

  ```js
  const myBet = document.getElementById("bet");
  const btnCalculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

  btnCalculate.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(myBet.value); /*I am access value here*/
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <input id="bet" type="text" value="">
  <img id="calculate" src="btn-submit.png" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In your code the variable myBet is assigned the value when the code runs, at which point the input is still empty.

What you can do instead is store the input element as the variable and then read it's value when the button is clicked.

```js
const myBet = document.getElementById("bet");
const btnCalculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

btnCalculate.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(myBet.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="bet" type="text" value="">
<img id="calculate" src="btn-submit.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myBet = document.getElementById("bet");
const btnCalculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

btnCalculate.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(myBet.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="bet" type="text" value="">
<img id="calculate" src="btn-submit.png" />
```

Remove value from `document.getElementById("bet");`

```
const myBet = document.getElementById("bet");
  const btnCalculate = document.getElementById("calculate");
        
  btnCalculate.onclick = function(event) {
     console.log(myBet.value);
  }
```